# How to calculate PMF of Y if Y is a function of X?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I  have a function Y = X1 * X2

X1 is a discrete variable between the range (0,100) and X2 is also a discrete variable in the same range of (0,100). I have computed ALL possible values of Y for each of X1 and X2, so I have 10,000 values of Y for each combination of 100 X1's and 100 X2's.

Now let's say I know the PMF of both X1 and X2 to be some function.

**What is the most correct way to represent the PMF of Y and to summarize its mean and variance?**

Naively, it seems like there are 2 approaches:

1. I can compute the distribution of Y based on my computed 10,000 values of Y alone and ignore the PMF of X1 and X2 entirely. The mean and var can also be calculated from these 10,000 values.
2. I can derive the probability of each Y value as P(X1) * P(X2). I can also derive the the mean of Y as E(Y) = E(X1) * E(X2) (as the function is X1 * X2)

It looks like both these approaches yield different results though for both PMF and mean/variance - so which is the more correct approach?

**More philosophically, are these 2 approaches answering different questions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a **joint PMF** for $(X_1, X_2)$, then the PMF of $Y$ is
$$P(Y=y) = \sum_{x_1, x_2 \text{ such that } y=x_1x_2} P(X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2).$$
That is, you consider all possible pairs of values $(x_1, x_2)$ whose product is $y$, and sum the joint PDF of $(X_1, X_2)$ over those pairs.

The mean of $Y$ can be computed as
$$E[Y] = \sum_{x_1} \sum_{x_2} x_1 x_2 P(X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2)$$
where the sums are over all values $x_1$ that $X_1$ can take, and all values $x_2$ that $X_2$ can take.

---

If you are assuming that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are **independent** and you have the individual PMFS of each random variable, then you can replace $P(X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2)$ with $P(X_1=x_1) \cdot P(X_2 = x_2)$ in my above answers. In particular the expectation will decompose as $E[Y] = E[X_1] E[X_2]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, my assumption is that X1 and X2 are independent so it sounds like approach #2 is the correct way of doing things. However I must ask, since I know the entire solution space of Y, why can't I just compute the mean and distribution of all 10,000 Y values i.e instead of using PMFs of X? More interestingly, why does this approach result in a different mean of Y? My guess is its answering a different quesion but I am not sure what that is...

Comment: @Anubhav If you do that, you are tacitly assuming that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are each uniformly distributed over the values it can take. (That is, $X_1$ is equally likely to take any of its possible values, etc.)